# Marketing Cloud Send Preview

Tags: marketing-cloud

If you unsubscribe in a test send, will it unsubscribe that contact?

I have selected 'Send Preview' with a random contact from our data extensions and sent a test send to myself to confirm the links are working correctly. I selected the 'unsubscribe' link as a test of functionality, have I now unsubscribed the email address that was selected in the Send Preview?

Answer (score 0):

If you clicked on the unsubscribe link from a test email, then that record will be unsubscribed. You will need to search for that Subscriber in the All Subscribers list and change their status back to Active.

Comment: Thanks for your help Eliot! Do you know of a way to test the unsubscribe link functions without unsubscribing the email that the test is associated with? It is important for us to test due to CASL to ensure that recipients can unsubscribe should they wish to, so a bit frustrating that this will happen every time it is tested. Any tips would be appreciated.